# ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I was getting an odd error in one of my C# Batch Jobs, so I decided to rebuild it piece by piece to find out what was causing the problem. Turns out it is something called a `ConfigurationErrorsException` which I have never seen before. here is the inner exception:

```
Configuration system failed to initialize System.Exception {System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException}
```

`

This is thrown when I attempt to fill a variable by accessing the `app.config`. Below is the entirety of the code that I have so far

```
using System;
using BatchDashboard;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;


namespace LVODRM
{
    class Program
    {
        //Job log and BatchDashboard variables
        private static StreamWriter _Log;
        //public static string _environment = getEnvironment();
        public const string _PACKAGENAME = "LVOONX";

        //BatchDashboard variables
        public static int xmlRecordCount = 0;
        public static int xmlProcessedCount = 0;
        public static int errorCount = 0;
        public static int warningCount = 0;

        //MQ and Parsing variables
        public static string strReturn;
        public static string queueName;
        public static string pathToSave;
        public static string strQueueManager;
        public static int backOutNumberThreshold;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            strReturn = string.Empty;
            queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("QueueName");

            Console.Write("Hello world");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config file. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
    <section name="LVODRM.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
  <!--MQ SETTINGS-->
  <add key="QueueName" value="LVO.DRM.PRODUCER.NEWAPT"/>
  <add key="PathToSave" value="\\prdhilfs02\L&amp;I-SYSTEMS\WORKAREA\AgencySystems\Public\NMF_Onyx\NMFDatafiles\NMFImportFiles\"/>
  <add key="QueueManager" value="MQT_DMB01"/>
  <add key="BackOutNumberThreshold" value="10"/>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `<appSettings>` tag. E.g:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="QueueName" value="LVO.DRM.PRODUCER.NEWAPT"/>
    ...
</appSettings>
```